# Qt Creator and external libraries fail to link (HALCON)

Tags: qt, linker, 32-bit, qmake

ive been googling the net for hours now and still didnt came up with a solution to my problem, so i hope that you guys can help me.
Im trying to add external libraries to my Qt Project (4.7.4 32-bit). I'm working with the CV-Software Halcon (x86-win32) and want to link the example test project (matching.pro) to the halconcpp.lib and halcon.lib inside the lib folder of Halcon. So i added the following lines to the .pro file.

```
#includes
INCLUDEPATH += C:/"Program Files"/MVTec/HALCON/include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/"Program Files"/MVTec/HALCON/include/cpp
#libs
LIBS            += C:/"Program Files"/MVTec/HALCON/lib/x86-win32/halconcpp.lib
LIBS            += C:/"Program Files"/MVTec/HALCON/lib/x86-win32/halcon.lib
```

But unfortunately the compilation process still produces linking errors:

```
release/qhalconwindow.o:qhalconwindow.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Halcon18set_window_extentsElllll'
release/qhalconwindow.o:qhalconwindow.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Halcon12close_windowEl'
release/qhalconwindow.o:qhalconwindow.cpp:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Halcon12close_windowEl'
release/qhalconwindow.o:qhalconwindow.cpp:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Halcon12close_windowEl' 
etc...
```

So im thinking that it has something to do with the settings of qmake, especially the way in which it links to the halconcpp.lib.
And because im quite a noob when it comes to compiler settings, my only hope is your knowledge.

Thanks for taking the time to help me ! :)
I highly appreciate it.
greets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the `halconlibs` arent compatible with `Mingw`, they are only compatible with the Visual C++ compiler.

When I switched over to VisualStudio with Qt plugin, everything worked flawlessly.

I hope this helps anybody stumbling across this question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually adding the external library to the .pro file u can do one thing.

Right click on your main project, then select "add library" option then it will ask for

1. External library
2. Internal Library
3. System Library

then select External library , and rest all thing is done by the Qt Creator i.e it will automatically add the path to the .pro file and link the library to your project.

Comment: that didnt make a difference :S. still the same problem. is it possible that its related to qmake and how it is trying to link to the lib. i mean, do you know any commands or flags in particular i should take a closer look at?

Comment: it might be related to qmake, but if we follow the above steps qt creator wil automatically link the library. In my case it worked..